# Why does adding a return() in a for loop make a difference?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm playing around for loops in R, and have my data as `x < -data.frame(rnorm(5))`
Then I'm doing a for loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
  x$new[i] <- x$rnorm.5.[i] + 1
  return(x)
}
```

It returns

```
              rnorm.5.   new
            0.4036397   1.40364
            1.1424362   1.40364
            0.2314323   1.40364
            0.7248371   1.40364
            0.6802016   1.40364
```

with all value in the `new` column the same.

However, if I remove the `return(x)`, or change it into `print(x)`, it instead gives me a different df:

```
              rnorm.5.   new
            0.4036397   1.40364
            1.1424362   1.1424362
            0.2314323   1.2314323
            0.7248371   1.7248371
            0.6802016   1.6802016
```

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: when you return, the loop ends. When you print, the loop keeps going

Comment: @LioraHaydont please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `return(x)`, it ends the function, even if it's inside of a loop, so the loop stops here and doesn't loop anymore.

When you write `print(x)`, it prints but the function and the loop keep going

Additionnal info provided by @Amar :

`return` will pass whatever value out of the function/loop for usage, while `print` simply prints to the console. For example, if you want the output of a function to be assigned for later usage, you'd use `return`

Comment: Adding to this great answer: `return` will pass whatever value out of the function/loop for usage, while `print` simply prints to the console. For example, if you want the output of a function to be assigned for later usage, you'd use `return`.

Comment: Thank you Liora Haydont and @Amar. Really detailed and helpful explanation!